Problem with geomatics web application and displaying the attribut table when a layer is clicked
I am trying to set up a web application that allows me to display a layer I have made on ARCGIS, and converted to WFS through QGIS, I have published the layer on geoserver , and was able to display the layer on a base map with leaflet and open layers6,I am working with visual code and set up an html code ,  would like to display information from the layer's attribut table when I click on a certain polygon (the layer includes multiple polygons) but this has not worked for me.
it's okay if the webapp is only published locally.
how can I solve this ?
